# How to echo user input in Scala REPL?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I'm teaching an introductory programming class, using Scala. We are starting with the REPL. The REPL has a bug in that, when the student enters a readLine command, their input is not echoed. Is there some workaround that I can suggest or provide?

I don't have this trouble when using Eclipse, but it will be some weeks before I introduce Eclipse to my students.

Comment: @som-snytt `reader.readLine` doesn't work with 2.10 for some weird reason. I am guessing that's the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use *power mode* to get access to the REPL's reader; it will give you a fully working `readLine`:

```
scala> :power
** Power User mode enabled - BEEP WHIR GYVE **
** :phase has been set to 'typer'.          **
** scala.tools.nsc._ has been imported      **
** global._, definitions._ also imported    **
** Try  :help, :vals, power.<tab>           **

scala> repl.in.readLine("enter something: ")
enter something: hello world
res0: String = hello world

scala>
```

**Edit**: as @som-snytt pointed out, in 2.11 you can use `reader` instead of `repl.in` in the above code, which is both shorter and easier to remember.

Comment: Thanks! repl.in.readLine works perfectly; reader.readLine does not.
<br>
On my Mac, I get error: not found: value reader<br>
On Windows, I get error: value reader in class Global cannot be accessed in scala.tools.nsc.Global
<br>
repl.in.readLine is probably better for my students in any case, as it emphasizes that this is only for the REPL.

Answer (score 2):

Use `scala -Xnojline` :

```
scala> val l = readLine
test
l: String = test
```

This does however break some things, in particular arrow keys, so you can't modify previous commands.

If available, you can use `rlwrap scala -Xnojline` (should be available on cygwin too) to restore those functionalities.

Full credit to [this post](http://brizzled.clapper.org/blog/2009/04/29/readline-support-in-scalas-repl/).